# difference in two file using ansible module

Tags: ansible

I want to see if there is any changes in the file one present in local and other on the remote host. If there is any difference, it should be visible in screen
what should be the best way to do this using Ansible

For example:

```
src : /tmp/abc.txt
dest : hostname:/tmp/cde.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `check_mode: yes` and `diff: yes` tasks options to show differences:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "Only show diff between test1.txt & test2.txt" 
      copy:
        src: /tmp/test2.txt
        dest: /tmp/test1.txt
      check_mode: yes
      diff: yes
```

Example:

```
# cat /tmp/test1.txt
test1

# cat /tmp/test2.txt
test1
test2

# ansible-playbook diff.yaml
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Only show diff between test1.txt & test2.txt] ************************************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/test1.txt
+++ after: /tmp/test2.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 test1
+test2

changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

More information on `check_mode` & `diff` [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html).

Comment: thanks.. the point is one of the file exists in localhost and other on remote host

Comment: `copy` copy file from ansible machine to remote one

Comment: This doesn't work on Ansible 2.9

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a task you can do with the [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) module. Use [diff](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) to get the diff of both files. Register the output and use debug for display:

```
- name: Generate diff
  command: diff  /tmp/abc.txt  /tmp/def.txt
  register: diff_result

- name: Show diff result
  debug:
    var: diff_result
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line,

```
ansible <host-pattern> -m copy -CD -a "src=<your local file> dest=<remote file or location>"
```

The `-m copy` option causes Ansible to invoke the *copy* module

The `-C` option causes Ansible to *Check* whether a change would occur, rather than perform the copy

The `-D` option causes Ansible to report what changes would occur if the copy were to be made

Output is similar to what the UNIX `diff` command produces, only this reports differences between a local file and remote copies.

Answer (score -1):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
   - name: Get ansible date/time facts
     setup:
       filter: "ansible_date_time"
       gather_subset: "!all"

   - name: Store DTG as fact
     set_fact:
       DTG: "{{ ansible_date_time.date }}"

   - name: Changes of the USCORE_Switch
     copy:
       src: /home/thilan_widearea_cloud/network-programmability/curentconfig/backups/{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}/USNYCL3SW-{{hostvars.localhost.DTG}}-config.txt
       dest: /home/thilan_widearea_cloud/network-programmability/curentconfig/USBaseconfig.txt
     check_mode: yes
     diff: yes
     register: output
```