# Ansible Module to generate difference between two strings

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook whose tasks generate 2 strings and I need to compare them and give the difference between them as output.

I have read about 'diff' command https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820999/9797983 with which we can generate the difference between 2 files or directories. But it doesn't work with strings.

Is there any command or module available in ansible which will give the difference between two strings??

Comment: What do you mean with difference? Strings can be equal or different or one string could be a substring of the other one etc. anyway you could use the diff command within the shell module

Comment: Why dont you use the `assert` module to do this comparison for you?

Answer (score 0):

To use the diff command inside the shell module you could run it like this:

```
ansible localhost -m shell -a '/bin/bash -c "diff <(echo {{ a }}) <(echo {{ b }})"' -e 'a=hello b=hello'
```